# Untangling JS Source from Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure

There is [a javascript application](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/agent8ball) I would like to modify for my use<sup>*</sup>. The problem is, the js is compiled with Google Closure Compiler. Obviously, I should modify the sources (which are available in the repository), and re-compile.

This is my first encounter with GCC. I skimmed the documentation and came to the conclusion that the key is using the sources mentioned in [deps.js](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/agent8ball/blob/master/public/javascripts/deps.js) via `goog.addDependency` keywords.
So I set up an HTML file and referenced all the sources. Loading this file I got 118 *ReferenceError: goog is not defined* errors in firebug console.

Then I read some more and found the app has been compiled with the help of [kbuild](https://github.com/kevmoo/kbuild), and that it uses a config file, [config.kb](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/agent8ball/blob/master/config.kb), to send the right parameters to GCC. This file, indicates the first file should be [loader.js](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/agent8ball/blob/master/public/javascripts/eightball/loader.js), so I reordered the `<script>` tags and moved

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./eightball/loader.js"></script>
```

to the top. but the same errors are thrown. So, what is missing?

<sub>* The license is MIT and there is no issue with the rights.</sub>

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder

Comment: @Matt you deleted your answer just in time to duck getting a +1 ;) Thanks for the answer and this pointer.

Comment: Haha, I can undelete it if you found it useful, but I thought I'd misread your question, and you'd already completed what I said in my answer, and are instead looking at how to minify the code using Closure Compiler... in which case the above link is what you need :).

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. You are right the question is a bit long, but your first impression was correct -- I have not succeeded in getting the uncompiled version working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it would seem the application is using [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/), which is a JavaScript library developed by Google.

<sup>This is (*of course*), ***completely*** different to [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), which is a JavaScript minification and obfuscation engine (dang these large companies and their quest to name everything the same).</sup>

That means you should include the Closure bootstrap *before* deps you've got listed; which is what the application itself does, as in the [main view](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/agent8ball/blob/master/app/views/main/index.haml), it calls the [`game_js` helper](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/agent8ball/blob/master/app/helpers/main_helper.rb), which [includes](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/agent8ball/blob/master/app/helpers/main_helper.rb#L9-10) the `base` file of Closure if the application hasn't been compiled.

---

**TLDR:**

Try including the `/javascripts/closure/closure/goog/base.js` file first.